# Combine multiple events in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I created this sample chart. 
The lines and the legend are interactive: when the mouse is over the line on the graph (or the text or the circle of the legend) the corresponding line becomes with opacity 1.
Also, when you click on an item in the legend (text or circle) the corresponding line is hidden.

The two events work separately, but not together.
When I disable a line and then I go over with mouse on the legend (immediately) or on the line, it is displayed with opacity 1 because of the event that changes the opacity.

This is a piece of code:

```
dataNest.forEach(function(d, i) {

        d.values = d.values.sort(function(a, b) { return a.year -b.year; }); 

        // create line 
        svg.append("path")
            .classed("line", 'true')
            .classed('tag' + d.key.replace(/\s+/g, ''), true) 
            .style("stroke", color(i))                          
            .style("opacity", 0.5)
            .attr("d", valueline(d.values))
            .on("mouseover", function() {
                d3.selectAll(".tag" + d.key.replace(/\s+/g, '')) 
                    .style("opacity", 1);
            })
            .on("mouseout", function() {
                d3.selectAll(".tag" + d.key.replace(/\s+/g, '')) 
                    .style("opacity", 0.5);
            });     

        svg.append("text")
            .attr("x", width + 58)  
            .attr("y", i * 28 + 4)          
            .attr("class", "legend")
            .style("fill", color(i))                                
            .text(d.key)                                    
            .on("click", function() {                           
                var active = d.active ? false : true;           
                var newOpacity = active ? 0 : 0.5;
                var newColorFill = active ? "white" : color(i); 
                d3.selectAll(".tag" + d.key.replace(/\s+/g, ''))    
                    .transition().duration(150)   
                    .style("opacity", newOpacity);  
                d3.selectAll(".circle" + d.key.replace(/\s+/g, ''))         
                    .transition().duration(150)   
                    .style("fill", newColorFill); 
                d.active = active;                                  
            })
            .on("mouseover", function() {
                d3.selectAll(".tag" + d.key.replace(/\s+/g, '')) 
                    .style("opacity", 1);
            })
            .on("mouseout", function() {
                d3.selectAll(".tag" + d.key.replace(/\s+/g, '')) 
                    .style("opacity", 0.5);
            });

        svg.append("circle")
            .classed("circle", 'true')
            .classed('circle' + d.key.replace(/\s+/g, ''), true) 
            .attr("cx", width + 40) 
            .attr("cy", i * 28)                                      
            .attr("r", 10)                          
            .attr("stroke", color(i))
            .attr("stroke-width", 3)
            .style("fill", color(i))                    
            .on("click", function() {                   
                var active = d.active ? false : true;           
                var newOpacity = active ? 0 : 0.5; 
                var newColorFill = active ? "white" : color(i);
                d3.selectAll(".tag" + d.key.replace(/\s+/g, '')) 
                    .transition().duration(150)   
                    .style("opacity", newOpacity); 
                d3.selectAll(".circle" + d.key.replace(/\s+/g, ''))     
                    .transition().duration(150)   
                    .style("fill", newColorFill); 
                d.active = active;                                      
            })
            .on("mouseover", function() { 
                d3.selectAll(".tag" + d.key.replace(/\s+/g, '')) 
                    .style("opacity", 1);
            })
            .on("mouseout", function() {
                d3.selectAll(".tag" + d.key.replace(/\s+/g, '')) 
                    .style("opacity", 0.5);
            });
...
}
```

The entire code is here: https://plnkr.co/edit/RRw9f6kk4nataJL2OQfQ?p=preview

I also tried using the variable `active` outside, that is, by doing so:

```
dataNest.forEach(function(d, i) {

d.values = d.values.sort(function(a, b) { return a.year -b.year; }); 

var active = d.active ? false : true;   

// create line 
svg.append("path")
    .classed("line", 'true')
    .classed('tag' + d.key.replace(/\s+/g, ''), true) 
    .style("stroke", color(i))                          
    .style("opacity", 0.5)
    .attr("d", valueline(d.values))
    .on("mouseover", function() {
        d3.selectAll(".tag" + d.key.replace(/\s+/g, '')) 
            .style("opacity", 1);
    })
    .on("mouseout", function() {
        d3.selectAll(".tag" + d.key.replace(/\s+/g, '')) 
            .style("opacity", 0.5);
    });     

svg.append("text")
    .attr("x", width + 58)  
    .attr("y", i * 28 + 4)          
    .attr("class", "legend")
    .style("fill", color(i))                                
    .text(d.key)                                    
    .on("click", function() {                           
        //var active = d.active ? false : true;         
        var newOpacity = active ? 0 : 0.5;
        var newColorFill = active ? "white" : color(i); 
        d3.selectAll(".tag" + d.key.replace(/\s+/g, ''))    
            .transition().duration(150)   
            .style("opacity", newOpacity);  
        d3.selectAll(".circle" + d.key.replace(/\s+/g, ''))         
            .transition().duration(150)   
            .style("fill", newColorFill); 
        d.active = active;                                  
    })
    .on("mouseover", function() {
        if(active)
          d3.selectAll(".tag" + d.key.replace(/\s+/g, '')).style("opacity", 1);
    })
    .on("mouseout", function() {
      if(active)
          d3.selectAll(".tag" + d.key.replace(/\s+/g, '')).style("opacity", 0.5);
    });

svg.append("circle")
    .classed("circle", 'true')
    .classed('circle' + d.key.replace(/\s+/g, ''), true) 
    .attr("cx", width + 40) 
    .attr("cy", i * 28)                                      
    .attr("r", 10)                          
    .attr("stroke", color(i))
    .attr("stroke-width", 3)
    .style("fill", color(i))                    
    .on("click", function() {                   
        var active = d.active ? false : true;           
        var newOpacity = active ? 0 : 0.5; 
        var newColorFill = active ? "white" : color(i);
        d3.selectAll(".tag" + d.key.replace(/\s+/g, '')) 
            .transition().duration(150)   
            .style("opacity", newOpacity); 
        d3.selectAll(".circle" + d.key.replace(/\s+/g, ''))     
            .transition().duration(150)   
            .style("fill", newColorFill); 
        d.active = active;                                      
    })
    .on("mouseover", function() { 
      if(active)
          d3.selectAll(".tag" + d.key.replace(/\s+/g, '')).style("opacity", 1);
    })
    .on("mouseout", function() {
      if(active)
          d3.selectAll(".tag" + d.key.replace(/\s+/g, '')).style("opacity", 0.5);
    });

    ...

}); // end dataNest.forEach
```

But it doesn't work, why?

I know that the code is a little (actually very) messy but I just started using d3 so I have not yet to understand how to organize the code.

Thank you

Comment: What two events are you trying to do ?

Comment: @thatOneGuy What do you mean? Maybe I explained very bad. I wish I could turn off the lines by clicking on the corresponding legend, and I would also like that the lines become with opacity 1 when, with mouse, I go over over them or when I go over over the corresponding legend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK actually you have done everything but forgot to do an if check.

Here's the result : https://plnkr.co/edit/EakWo8xD4WDkWa7o59bd?p=preview

I just added

```
if(!d.active){
                d3.selectAll(".tag" + d.key.replace(/\s+/g, '')) 
                    .style("opacity", 1);}
```

if lines to your mouseevent to check whether your data is active or not.

Comment: I tried `if(active)` and not `if(! active)`. It was easy. Thank you so much!